# How to limit the number of images shown in a treeview?

Tags: php, qtreeview

Good day everyone!

Im currently building my treeview project with images displayed on it. But Im stack on limiting the number of images displayed in every folder in the treeview. I want to limit the number of displayed images into 5 images only. I will greatly appreciate your help. Below are the codes of my treeview:

(Credits to the Original Owner of Treeview and to sir Ro Achterberg)

```
class TreeView
{
    private $root;
 
    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->root = $path;
    }
 
    public function getTree()
    {
        return $this->createStructure($this->root, true);
    }
 
    private function createStructure($directory, $root)
{

    $structure = $root ? '<br><div><h1>' : '<div>';

    $nodes = $this->getNodes($directory);

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $path = $directory.'/'.$node['name'];
        if (is_dir($path) ) {
            $structure .= '<div id="body">';
            $structure .= '<h4>'.$node['name'].'</h4>';
            $structure .= self::createStructure($path, false);
            $structure .= '</div><br><br>';
        } else {
            $path = str_replace($this->root.'/', null, $path);

            $structure .= '
                <div class="gallery">
                <a href="activities/'.$path.'" class="big">
                <img class="someClass" loading="lazy" src="activities/'.$path.'" width="185px" height="150px">
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>';

        }
    }

    return $structure.'</div>';
}
 
    private function getNodes($directory = null)
{
    $folders = [];
    $files = [];

    $nodes = scandir($directory);

    foreach ($nodes as $node){

        if (!$this->exclude($node)) {
            $entry = [ 'name' => $node, 'mtime' => filemtime("$directory/$node") ];
            if (is_dir($directory.'/'.$node)) {
                $folders[] = $entry;
            } else {
                $files[] = $entry;
            }
        }
    }

    $entries = array_merge($folders, $files);
    usort (
        $entries,
        function ($a, $b) { return $a['mtime'] < $b['mtime']; }
    );

    return $entries;
}
 
    private function exclude($filename)
    {
        return in_array($filename, ['.', '..', 'index.php', 'upload.php', '.htaccess', '.DS_Store']);
    }
}
 
$treeView = new TreeView('activities/');
echo $treeView->getTree();
```

Comment: display or limit?, if display then that's the job of clientside, i.e show more/less, which you can do with js, if its limit then [slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) $files before merging

Comment: @Sir Lawrence Cherone, its Limit sir. Im new to php sir, most of its features are still unfamiliar to me. Can u edit my code sir base on your suggestion? Id really appreciate it sir.